# Proof of a theorem on Plateau's problem in "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Andrew Presley

Tags: differential-geometry, line-integrals, greens-theorem, minimal-surfaces

I'm studying the proof of this theorem on Plateau's problem in the textbook "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Andrew Presley, but I don't understand, being more specific, why $\beta^0=\gamma^0=0$ in the final part. For first, let me enunciate the theorem:

**Theorem:** with the above notation, assumme that the surface $\varphi^{\tau}$ vanishes along the boundary curve $\pi$. then
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{A}(0))' = -2\int_{\operatorname{int}(\pi)} H(EG - F^2)^{1/2}\alpha du dv, \label{1}
\end{align}
where $H$ is the mean curvature of $\sigma$, $E$, $F$ and $G$ are the coefficients of its first fundamental form, and $\alpha = \varphi\cdot N$, where $N$ is the standar unit normal of $\sigma$.

And this is the proof:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think that reason is related with the following fact, $\varphi^{\tau}(u,v) = 0$ when $(u,v)$ is a point on the curve $\pi$ where $\varphi^{\tau}= (\sigma^{\tau})^{\prime}$, but i didn't get it to, any help will be really appreciate.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.

The theorem assumes that the surface variation $\varphi^\tau(u,v) = \mathbf{0}$ for every point $(u,v)$ on the boundary curve $\pi$.  Now, the equation
$$\varphi^\tau = \alpha^\tau \mathbf{N}^\tau + \beta^\tau\sigma^\tau_u + \gamma^\tau \sigma^\tau_v$$
holds for all points $(u,v)$ in the interior region $\text{Int}(\pi)$ and on the boundary curve $\pi$.  In particular, if $(u,v)$ is on the boundary, then:
$$\mathbf{0} = \alpha^\tau(u,v) \mathbf{N}^\tau + \beta^\tau(u,v) \sigma^\tau_u + \gamma^\tau(u,v) \sigma^\tau_v.$$
Since $\{\mathbf{N}^\tau, \sigma^\tau_u, \sigma^\tau_v\}$ is linearly independent, it follows that for every point $(u,v)$ on the boundary curve $\pi$:
$$\alpha^\tau(u,v) = 0, \ \ \ \beta^\tau(u,v) = 0, \ \ \ \gamma^\tau(u,v) = 0.$$
Setting $\tau = 0$, we arrive at the claim.

Comment: Thank you so much! i finally get, may i bother you with one more question? please, i dont understand at all  why if $\varphi ^{\tau}(u.v)=0$ implies that $(u,v)$ is a point on the boundary curve $\pi$

Comment: You have it backwards.  It should be: If $(u,v)$ is a point on $\pi$, then $\varphi^\tau(u,v) = \mathbf{0}$.  This is simply the assumption "$\varphi^\tau$ vanishes along the boundary" in the statement of the theorem.